# R: overwrite rules that apriori produced

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I want to overwrite confidence values of an apriori output, then put the output into is.redundant. I got an error at the last line. How do you do it?

```
library(arules)
data(Groceries) # read sample data
# find apriori rules
outApriori = apriori(Groceries, 
                     parameter = list(support=0.001, confidence=0.70, minlen=1, maxlen=4)
                     ,appearance = list(rhs = "whole milk"  ) )
dfApriori = as.data.frame(inspect(outApriori[1:5])) # convert into data.frame
# modify the confidence value conservatively by adding one error sample
(estimateConfidence= dfApriori$count / (1 + round( dfApriori$count / dfApriori$confidence ) ))
dfApriori$confidence = estimateConfidence
outRmRedundant <- dfApriori[!is.redundant(dfApriori)] # Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 

# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#             unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.redundant’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
```

Comment: What error do you get? You might get some quick info/answer if you include the full text of the error.

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: `dfApriori` is a frame, whereas `is.redundant` [expects a set of rules](https://rdrr.io/cran/arules/man/is.redundant.html). Where are your rules?

Comment: My rule is outApriori . But I want to edit my rules outApriori . So far, I haven't found a way to do both edit my rules and is.redundant.

Comment: `is.redundant` is expecting *rules*, not a *frame*, so regardless of what you want, `is.redundant(dfApriori)` will not ever work. I'm not familiar with what you are trying to accomplish, but `is.redundant` is intended to be run on a set of rules in order to filter a set of rules, neither operation intending to work on a frame.

Comment: The help documentation for it has an a good example (using different data, of course), of how/when to use `is.redundant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `is.redundant()` expects a `rules` object not a `data.frame`. Here is how you change the quality slot of the `rules` object:

```
library(arules)
data(Groceries)
# find apriori rules
rules <- apriori(Groceries, 
  parameter = list(support=0.001, confidence=0.70, minlen=1, maxlen=4),
  appearance = list(rhs = "whole milk"))

estimatedConfidence <- quality(rules)$count / (1 + round(quality(rules)$count / quality(rules)$confidence))

quality(rules)$confidence <- estimatedConfidence

rules.nonredundant <- rules[!is.redundant(rules)] 
inspect(head(rules.nonredundant))
```

BTW: You might want to look at Laplace Corrected Confidence (http://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html#laplace) which can be calculated using the function `interestMeasure()`.

Comment: Super! That was exactly what I wanted. Many thanks for giving me what I needed, for introducing Laplace Corrected Confidence to me, and for developing arules.